# Can file handles be translated to filenames?

Tags: files, solaris, open-files

Is there a tool for translating file handles to file names on Solaris 10?

I've looked around and found several scripts including the one at:
http://heim.ifi.uio.no/kjetilho/hacks/fhfind.perl
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.solaris/JixDbMSIdws

The first returns:

```
$ fhfind.pl  60000000 db18ad03 20080000 1bcba9 6cf2d513 d4d3d955 60000000 db18ad00
Sorry, can't find device.
```

The second returns:

```
$ fhfind  60000000 db18ad03 20080000 1bcba9 6cf2d513 d4d3d955 60000000 db18ad00
Cannot find filesystem for devid 60000000
```

Neither seem to work on Solaris 10 and are quite dated.

Comment: I don't have solaris, but generally if you look at an NFS file handle, you can find the inumber is embedded inside it at a particular (OS-dependent) offset, as well as the `st_rdev` corresponding to the underlying file system.  From that you can use a utility like `ncheck` or `find /wherever -xdev -inum NNN` to find links to the file.  My guess is that the file handle format changed since those scripts were written.

Comment: Also be aware that posting NFS file handles publicly potentially opens you up to attack, if someone can get packets to port 2049 of your server, especially if the file handle happens to correspond to a directory.  If you are at all worried about security, the `fsirand` program will re-randomize your generation numbers.

Comment: As @user3188445 pointed out, the file handle format has likely changed.  Worth reverse-engineering it to figure out the format on your release/platform, see good example at http://syslog.eu/stale-nfs-file-handle-sparc-zfs

Comment: @steve, just wondering, what is the date on that post? Is that year 2015? It looks interesting, but I don't get a hit in the first instance... the `echo | memstat` command doesn't look like it matches anything for me.

Comment: Date on that post is April 2013 (see http://syslog.eu/2013/04).  Did you mean `echo ::nfs_exptable | mdb -k` rather than `echo | memstat` ?

Comment: @steve, yes. was in a bit of haste.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're getting your file handle from, or end goal.  Have you looked to see if using `pfiles` to gather data from the proc table gives you what you're looking for?

Comment: here's an example NFS error where file handle is reported and a filename translation would be helpful: `nfs: [ID 626546 kern.notice] NFS write error on host 10.97.15.15: Stale NFS file handle.
nfs: [ID 702911 kern.notice] (file handle: 60000000 c716ad03 20080000 10f863 b5f6ba05 6c35cb55 60000000 c716ad00)`